# GNU screen - Unable to reattach to screen after lost connection

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I was using irssi in screen but lost connection. After I ssh'd back in to the server, I can no longer attach to that screen. screen -ls shows that the screen is already attached.

I tried **screen -D** to force detach it, and it said detach but screen -ls still says it's attached. I tried **screen -x** and it just hangs there.

```
[sub@server ~]$ screen -ls 
There are screens on:
 4033.poe (Detached)
 7728.irssi (Attached)
2 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-sub.
```

What can I do now?

Answer (score 17):

If you are trying to connect the 'Attached' screen, then run `screen -xr irssi`. The uppercase '-X' sends a command to one of the screen sessions, the lowercase '-x' option allows you to reconnect to an attached session.  But you still need to give the session name since there is more than one.

Answer (score 9):

I have cleared this behavior up in the past by killing the *shell* that started the screen session. Basically, killing all bash instances for my user that were *not* owned by screen.

Comment: Tried all options(-RD, -xr) mentioned here and could not recover the session. Ended up killing the SCREEN session by finding (ps -ef | grep bash) it.

Answer (score 4):

You gave it a non-default name. Try this: `screen -RD irssi`

Comment: i have a similar issue, but screen -RD <name> still hangs ... :-(

Answer (score 4):

you can try:

```
#Reattach a session and if necessary detach it first.
screen -d -r 7728.irssi  

#Reattach a session. If necessary detach and logout remotely first.
screen -D -r 7728.irssi
```

it's always a good idea use the full name `pid.tty`

Answer (score 3):

`screen` is known for not being backwards-compatible between versions. If the version of `screen` was updated on the server, it might be possible that you cannot reattach to older screen sessions anymore.

In that case, you can either use the old SCREEN binary to reattach (provided your distribution package manager saved it somewhere), or kill the session altogether.

Answer (score 2):

I have had some success by sending the GNU/screen process a SIGCHLD (which it normally receives when a window is closed), this forces it to touch (and possibly recreate) the socket file.

Also note that there are two ways to invoke the `screen` executable that only differ in case: `SCREEN` is the server-side component you are attempting to reconnect to, while `screen` is the client-side that shuffles data between your terminal and the server-side. So you might want to try killing the lower-case version...

For instance in the following you can see that my `screen` and `SCREEN` processes are not considered to be parent and child, indicating that I have attached to an existing session.

```
# ps fao pid,command
25070 SCREEN -U
25071  \_ vim +let &t_Co=256
25073  \_ -bash
25077  \_ -bash
...
18364  \_ sshd: username [priv]
18366  |   \_ sshd: username@pts/17
18367  |       \_ -bash
  870  |           \_ screen -U -x
```

Fresh sessions look more like this:

```
19645  |  \_ screen -S MySession
19646  |      \_ SCREEN -S MySession
19647  |          \_ bash
 1485  |          |   \_ python
19700  |          \_ bash
```

Comment: How to send a SIGCHILD?

Comment: Use the scarily named `kill` command like so: `kill -s SIGCHLD <PID>` where `<PID>` is the Process ID number (left-most column in my example output)

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me while I was using vi where the session froze and I disconnected. When attempting to reattach to screen using screen -Arx, the process would just hang.

There might be a similar child process running causing screen to hang. If you recall one in particular focus on that, otherwise to get a list of the child process running under your screen do:

```
ps ux -H
```

Which will show the nested child processes:

```
zwood    28481  0.0  0.0 101148  8844 ?        Ss   Oct07   1:36 SCREEN -S mysession
zwood    28482  0.0  0.0  67436  1744 pts/2    Ss+  Oct07   0:00   /bin/bash
zwood    28515  0.0  0.0  67556  1876 pts/4    Ss+  Oct07   0:00   /bin/bash
zwood     4498  0.0  0.0  67436  1772 pts/5    Ss   Oct07   0:00   /bin/bash
zwood     2007  0.0  0.0  73604  1324 pts/5    S+   15:47   0:00     vi /home/zwood/.bashrc.custom
zwood    14670  0.0  0.0  67436  1768 pts/13   Ss+  Oct14   0:00   /bin/bash
zwood    27002  0.0  0.0  67436  1720 pts/11   Ss+  Oct20   0:00   /bin/bash
zwood    24748  0.0  0.0  67432  1712 pts/14   Ss+  Oct21   0:00   /bin/bash
```

***After killing the vi process that caused the problem in the first place, I was able to reattach the screen without any issue.*** Killing any previous processes that had reattached to screen is probably a good idea as well. Just use:

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

I don't know what screen is doing in internally, why vi caused screen to hang, nor why killing the vi process brought my screen back. I've ran into this problem with screen in the past and had tried what most folks were recommending in this thread with no luck. Finding this problem child process is the only thing that has worked for me and has worked consistently at that.

Comment: A kill spree of processes under the screen was the only thing that saved me as well. I'd rather lose many processes under the screen, than lose the whole screen session!

Answer (score 0):

```
screen -r 4033

screen -x 7728
```

Answer (score 0):

```
killall -9 sshd
```

It worked for me. I had 3 different screens, and I've lost 3 different ssh connections. After reconnect, the screens were still attached, I issued the command above... of course I've lost my current connection, but it was a fresh one. On next reconnect, every screen were detached.

Note, if you are a superuser then you should use the `--user` option to kill only your ssh daemons.